# How to allow scripts to access OAuth token from yaml builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My build script uses the `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` environment variable.

In the designer build definition I checked *Allow scripts to access the OAuth token* and everything works.

After copying the designer generated YAML definition I cannot access the `SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` environment variable.

How do I allow my YAML build to access the OAuth Token?

This is my azure-pipelines.yaml:

```
queue:
  name: Hosted VS2017

steps:
- checkout: self
  lfs: true
  persistCredentials: true

- powershell: ./build.ps1
```

Comment: Is there any other option available other than 'self" for the - checkout? How to checkout a different repository, if you have another repository define under resources?

Comment: @phandinhlan The only options are `self` to checkout sources before build or `none` to run the build without sources. If you want to use the build for another repo, just drop the yaml file there. If you need additional repos you could checkout other sources with a script task.

Comment: thanks! I was struggling to find a way, but it seems there's no way.

Answer (score 28):

I found the solution in the [Pipeline Variable docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch): The variable must be declared in YAML.

At pipeline level for all jobs / tasks:

```
variables:
  system_accesstoken: $(System.AccessToken)

jobs:
  job: ...
```

Or at script / task level for example PowerShell:

```
- powershell: ./build.ps1
  env:
      system_accesstoken: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Comment: I tried doing this but for yml, do we need to specify this variable in the Variable tab as well in the yml definition?

Comment: You only need to define the variable in the yml.

Comment: Yes I got it. It needed to be spelled out in capitals for a third party task :)

Comment: The first option, adding a pipeline-level variable, did not work for me.  However, adding the environment specification for PowerShell tasks (Desktop or Core) worked.

Comment: The name of the environment variable passed to the PowerShell task needs to be in upper-case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken

Comment: The second option to add env in task worked for me

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me.

```
  - pwsh: |
      $pat = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
      Write-Host "PAT is: $pat"

      $getItemsUrl = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/git/repositories/$(Build.Repository.ID)/items?recursionLevel=Full&includeContentMetadata=true&api-version=6.0"
      Write-Host "url: $getItemsUrl"
      $data = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$getItemsUrl" -Headers @{Authorization = $pat}
      Write-Host "Raw data returned from Get Items API call: $data"

      Foreach ($i in $data.value)
      {
        Write-Host "Detailed data  returned from Get Items API call: $i"
      }
    env:
     SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    displayName: Power!
```