# Download artifact from Azure DevOps Pipeline grandparent Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Given 3 Azure DevOps Pipelines (more may exist), as follows:

1. Build, Unit Test, Publish Artifacts
2. Deploy Staging, Integration Test
3. Deploy Production, Smoke Test

**How can I ensure Pipeline 3 downloads the specific artifacts published in Pipeline 1?**

The challenge as I see it is that the Task `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` only offers a means to do this if the artifact came from the immediately preceding pipeline. By using the following Pipeline task:

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '$(System.TeamProjectId)'
    definition: 1
    specificBuildWithTriggering: true
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    artifactName: 'example.zip'
```

This works fine for a parent "triggering pipeline", but not a grandparent. Instead it returns the error message:

> Artifact example.zip was not found for build nnn.

where nnn is the run ID of the immediate predecessor, as though I had specified `pipelineId: $(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)`. Effectively, Pipeline 3 attempts to retrieve the Pipeline 1 artifact from Pipeline 2.  It would be nice if that `definition: 1` line did something, but alas, it seems to do nothing when `specificBuildWithTriggering: true` is set.

Note that `buildType: 'latest'` isn't safe; it appears it permits publishing an untested artifact, if emitted from Pipeline 1 while Pipeline 2 is running.

There may be no way to accomplish this with the `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2`. It's hard to be sure because [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) doesn't have much detail. Perhaps there's another reasonable way to accomplish this... I suppose publishing another copy of the artifact at each of the intervening pipelines, even the ones that don't use it, is one way, but not very reasonable. We could eliminate the ugly aspect of creating copies of the binaries, by instead publishing an artifact with the BuildId recorded in it, but we'd still have to retrieve it and republish it from every pipeline.

If there is a way to identify the original CI trigger, e.g. find the hash of the initiating GIT commit, I could use that to name and refer to the artifacts. Does [`Build.SourceVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) remain constant between triggered builds? Any other "Initiating ID" would work equally well.

You are welcome to comment on the example pipeline scenario, as I'm actually currently using it, but it isn't the point of my question. I think this problem is broadly applicable, as it will apply when building dependent packages, or for any other reasons for which "Triggers" are useful.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/58285153/846163.

Comment: Agreed sschmeck. The questions are of course different, since in your case you want the latest at the start of the pipeline, where you will lock it in with a simple pipeline variable. In my case I want the original trigger's artifact. However, the answer I just added here about using REST is very similar to the suggestion on your answer, and I'll link that below now.

Answer (score 2):

An [MS representative suggested using REST](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/5965) for this. For example:

```
HTTP GET https://dev.azure.com/ORGNAME/PROJECTGUID/_apis/build/Builds/2536
```

-

```
{
    "id": 2536,
    "definition": {
        "id": 17
    },
    "triggeredByBuild": {
        "id": 2535,
        "definition": {
            "id": 10
        }
    }
}
```

By walking the parents, one could find the ancestor with the desired definition ID (e.g. 10). Then its run ID (e.g. 2535) could be used to download the artifact.

@merlin-liang-msft suggested [a similar process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302129/608220) for a different requirement from @sschmeck, and their answer has accompanying code.

Comment: Very appreciate this solution shared here. You can accept this answer thus other SO users who has the same demand and issue could refer to this solution:-)

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT agreed, but I feel like the answer isn't complete without code. I'm trying to carve out time to submit a PR augmenting `DownloadPipelineArtifact@2` with this capability, then the answer will be available to all.

Comment: Very thanks for your serious and your contribution to our product. If need any help, just feel free to raise issue on our forum.

Answer (score 1):

There are [extensions that allow you to do this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.fetch-build-artifact), but the official solution it to [use a multi-stage pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and not 3 independent pipelines.

Comment: I currently use stages in my pipelines, to differentiate between parallel and sequential groupings of tasks. I appreciate your suggestion as totally valid, but hopefully there's another way that won't create new challenges for me.

Comment: The extension you linked is discontinued, and it doesn't look like it ensures the ancestor run artifact is used... just any run's artifact. That can already be accomplished with the built-in artifact task.

Answer (score 1):

One way is using release pipelines (you can't code/edit it in YAML) but you can use the same artifacts through whole deployment.

[Release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z7vQ.png)

You can also specify required triggers to start deployment on

[Approval and triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c78h.png)

Alternatively, there exist multi-stage pipeline, that are in preview.(https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/ ). 
You can access it by enabling it in your "preview feature".

Comment: This is a very interesting suggestion. We desired to add approval between steps 2 and 3. Investigating...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you output some pipeline artifacts with meta info and concatenate these in the preceding pipes like.

Grandparent >meta about pipe
Parent > meta about pipe and grantparent meta

Etc

Comment: Your solution makes sense to me. I think that's the approach I ultimately went with, questionmark? LOL. If I recall, there were still some challenges reliably identifying/maintaining the correct ancestor's metadata.