# DevOps Pipeline How do I fix this 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token'

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline and I want to tag the Azure Git repository

```
task: AssembyInfoReader@2
 displayName: Set Version numbers
 inputs:
   searchPattern: 'JLReyLibrary/Properties/GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs'
```

To get the assembly info variables.

Then this task causes an error:

```
task: GitTag@2
 displayName: Tag Repo to $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyInformationVersion)
 inputs:
   tag: '$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyInformationalVersion)'
   forceTagCreation: true
```

```
##[error]OAuth token not found. Make sure to have 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' enabled in the build definition.
```

How do I set the OAuth token?

## Clarification

I tried what was suggested below.

Now I have the following questions.

- How do I get the OAuth token?
- How do I get it in the   `env: Systems_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)`

I have found the `DevOps->Organizational Settings->OAuth Configurations

- Where do I find a description of the fields in the setting?

I am still getting the following error message:

`Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow scripts to access OAuth token from yaml builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837980/how-to-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-from-yaml-builds)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the task:

```
env:
  System_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)
```

So, in your case:

```
- task: GitTag@2
  displayName: Tag Repo to $(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyInformationVersion)
  inputs:
    tag: '$(AssemblyInfo.AssemblyInformationalVersion)'
    forceTagCreation: true
  env:
     System_AccessToken: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: When I add the "env:" the editor complains saying that this is not expected?

Comment: try to fix the indentation

Comment: Adding the `System_AccessToekn: $(System.AccessToken)`

Did not work. I still get the message 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token'

How Do I allow Scripts to acces OAuth Token.

Comment: @jl-rey Try to use GitTag@5 version task.