# how to enable Ouath authentication in build pipeline of Azure DevOps

Tags: oauth, azure-devops, pipeline

My build fails with below error. I want to get this option enabled in pipeline.
Could someone help me with how can I do this? I can select this option in additional options section in release pipeline. But not sure on how to do it in build pipeline.

##[error]OAuth token not found. Make sure to have 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' enabled in the build definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ##[error]OAuth token not found. Make sure to have 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' enabled in the build definition.

For this issue, check the option shown in the figure below in the agent job

[image]

For yaml pipeline, at script / task level for example PowerShell:

```
- powershell: ./build.ps1
  env:
      system_accesstoken: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Here is the [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837980/how-to-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-from-yaml-builds) you can refer to.

**Update**:

```
  - task: GitCopyDiff@1
    inputs:
      destination: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/diff'
      changeType: 'M'
    env: 
     SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried below still getting same issue   trigger:
- master
variables:
  system_accesstoken: $(System.AccessToken) - task: GitCopyDiff@1

  inputs:
    destination: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/diff'
    changeType: 'M'

Comment: How about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) : `env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)` In addition, check `System.AccessToken` 's [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope).

Comment: I am not able to declare the variable in the gitcopydiff task...this variable as per my understanding should be given in powershell/ bash task...so am not able to get it how can I make the task use the systemaccess token.

Comment: Thanq Lin it works...could u suggest me for this question if possible? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65032549/13460189